# Code Performance

Tags: java, performance

In both code single instance is used but I'm just wondering which approach is better

For e.g.:

An Interface

```
  interface A{

        void someOperation();

    }
```

Implementation of that interface

```
class AImpl implements A{
    private Object A;       

    public AImpl(Object A){
       this.A = A;
    }

   void someOpearion(){
   //

   ......
   //
    }

}
```

Factory interface

```
interface Factory{
    A getA();
}
```

Factory Implementation

```
class FactoryImpl implement Factory{
    A a;
    A getA(){
    if(a == null){
        a=new AImpl();
    }
    return a;
    }
}
```

Now There are two approaches with just 1 basic difference to use this Factory

**Approach 1:**

```
class View{

    View(){
       someMethod();
    }

    void someMethod(){
        factory.getA().someOperation();
    }
 }
```

**Approach 2:**

```
class View{
    A a;
    View(){
       this.a = factory.getA();
       someMethod();
    }

    void someMethod(){
        a.someOperation();
    }
 }
```

In approach 1 for every operation I need to access view using factory while in approach 2 I'm using factory instance locally.

I think approach 2 is better because its not using method Channing  or interface callback.Am I right Can some one explain elaborate this .

Answer (score 1):

Approach 2 can be marginally faster if you call `someMethod()` several times, since you save one method call. However, in real life this will not affect the runtime of your application, unless you make millions of calls.

I personally would chose between the two approaches based on maintainability and code simplicity. If you make the same call in several places within one class, I would use approach2. Otherwise approach 1  is simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: I agree with you there is just 1 issue with 2nd approach in 2nd approach we are using single reference but also using memory 2 times. so in limited memory we may face issue.

Answer (score 0):

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4041633/thomas-stets)
explained I too believe it depends on the situation, as almost all computer science approaches behave.

As your factory object creation in not thread safe, there is a higher probability to get multiple objects created of A in 1st approach in a multi-threaded environment. (2nd approach is not immune as well).

On the other hand 2nd approach adheres to the **"Has-A"** relationship in OOP, might come in handy when modeling your system.